# Highlight code in knitr .RMD document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Ive been reading through the Rstudio Markdown tutorials trying to figure out how to do syntax highlighting on my code in a .rmd file, but cant figure it out. Anyone know how to do it? My output goal right now is .html, but that can change if needed. Thanks!

A small code snippet of what I tried. The page text works fine but the code does not highlight:

````
---
title: Eve Historical Market Analysis
author: 
date: 12/3/18
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: cayman
    highlight: github
---
```
library(rmarkdown) #used for syntax highlighting in this document
library(shiny)
```
#read in file of item ids from website and parse
```
url = "http://eve-files.com/chribba/typeid.txt"
df = read_fwf(url, fwf_empty(url), skip = 2)
colnames = read_table(url, n_max = 1)
names(df) = names(colnames)
````

Comment: Do you want the code to run?  Or just to show example code?   Currently because you do not have `

Comment: you didn't put the code in a r chunk

Comment: Nope that isnt expected to run- its just a snippet from the top of my file to show what I have tried so far.

Comment: @s.brunel I was under the impression the ``` denoted an R chunk. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Rilcon42 ``` does not denote an R chunk unless you include `{r}` right after the ```, or in your case `{r, eval = FALSE}` (see the fourth example at [this page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_rcodechunks.html)). I think [Imran Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923194/imran-ali)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48079704/8386140) is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify the r code chunks as follows, and I hope it will produce what you are looking for

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(rmarkdown) #used for syntax highlighting in this document
library(shiny)
```
#read in file of item ids from website and parse

```{r code, eval=FALSE}
url = "http://eve-files.com/chribba/typeid.txt"
df = read_fwf(url, fwf_empty(url), skip = 2)
colnames = read_table(url, n_max = 1)
names(df) = names(colnames)
```
````

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: [rmarkdown cheatsheets](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-15.html) are very useful, within RStudio, click `Help` > `Cheatsheets` > `R Markdown Cheat Sheet`